# Book on homogenization of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I am currently searching for a nice book to read about homogenization of pde's (elliptic, parabolic or hyperbolic). I have found this one https://books.google.gr/books?id=s_hrxBdCu44C&redir_esc=y but I think I could use another opinion.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some useful books/lectures on homogenization theory:

[1] G. Allaire, Homogenization and two-scale convergence SIAM J. Math. Anal. 23.6
(1992) 1482-1518

[2] G. Allaire, Shape optimization by the homogenization method, Springer Verlag, New
York (2001)

[3] G. Allaire, C. Conca, Bloch wave homogenization and spectral asymptotic analysis, J.
Math. Pures et Appli. 77, pp.153-208 (1998)

[4] T. Arbogast, J. Douglas, U. Hornung, Derivation of the double porosity model of
single phase flow via homogenization theory, SIAM J. Math. Anal., 21 (1990), pp.
823-836

[5] N. Bakhvalov, G. Panasenko, Homogenization: Averaging Processes in Periodic Media
Kluwer, Dordrecht (1989)

[6] A. Bensoussan, J.L. Lions, G. Papanicolaou, Asymptotic Analysis for Periodic Structures North-Holland, Amsterdam (1978)

[7] A. Braides, Γ-convergence for beginners, Oxford Lecture Series in Mathematics and
its Applications, 22, Oxford University Press, Oxford (2002)

[8] R. Christensen, Mechanics of composite materials, John Wiley, New York (1979)

[9] D. Cioranescu, A. Damlamian, G. Griso, Periodic unfolding and homogenization, C.R.
Acad. Sci. Paris, Ser. 1, 335 (2002), pp. 99-104

[10] D. Cioranescu, A. Damlamian, and G. Griso, The periodic unfolding method in homogenization, SIAM J. Math. Anal. 40 (2008), no. 4, 1585-1620

[11] D. Cioranescu, P. Donato, An introduction to homogenization, Oxford Lecture Series
in Mathematics and Applications 17, Oxford (1999)

[12] G. Dal Maso, An Introduction to Γ-Convergence Birkh¨auser, Boston (1993)

[13] G. Dal Maso, L. Modica, Nonlinear stochastic homogenization and ergodic theory
Journal f¨ur die reine und angewandte Mathematik 368 (1986) 28-42

[14] E. De Giorgi, Sulla convergenza di alcune successioni di integrali del tipo dell’area
Rendi Conti di Mat. 8 (1975) 277-294

[15] E. De Giorgi, G-operators and Γ-convergence Proceedings of the international
congress of mathematicians (Warsazwa, August 1983), PWN Polish Scientific Publishers and North Holland (1984) 1175-1191

[16] E. De Giorgi, S. Spagnolo, Sulla convergenza degli integrali dell’energia per operatori
ellittici del secondo ordine Boll. Un. Mat. It. 8 (1973) 391-411

[17] U. Hornung, Homogenization and porous media, Interdisciplinary Applied Mathematics Series, vol. 6, (Contributions from G. Allaire, M. Avellaneda, J.L. Auriault, A.
Bourgeat, H. Ene, K. Golden, U. Hornung, A. Mikelic, R. Showalter), Springer Verlag
(1997)

[18] S. Kozlov, Averaging of random operators Math. USSR Sbornik 37 (1980) 167-180

[19] M. Lenczner, Homog´en´eisation d’un circuit ´electrique, C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris, Ser. 2,
324 (1997), pp. 537-542

[20] J.L. Lions, Some methods in the mathematical analysis of systems and their control
Science Press, Beijing, Gordon and Breach, New York (1981)

[21] G. Milton, The theory of composites, Cambridge University Press (2001)
[22] F. Murat, Compacit´e par compensation, Ann. Scuola Norm. Sup. Pisa Cl. Sci. 5,
pp.489-507 (1978)

[23] F. Murat, L. Tartar, H-convergence S´eminaire d’Analyse Fonctionnelle et Num´erique
de l’Universit´e d’Alger (1977). English translation in ”Topics in the mathematical
modeling of composite materials”, A. Cherkaev and R.V. Kohn ed., series ”Progress
in Nonlinear Differential Equations and their Applications”, 31, Birkh¨auser, Boston
(1997)

[24] G. Nguetseng, A general convergence result for a functional related to the theory of
homogenization SIAM J. Math. Anal. 20 (1989) 608-629

[25] O. Oleinik, A. Shamaev, G. Yosifian, Mathematical Problems in Elasticity and Homogenization Studies in Mathematics an Its Application 26 Elsevier, Amsterdam
(1992)

[26] G. Papanicolaou, S. Varadhan, Boundary value problems with rapidly oscillating random coefficients Colloquia Mathematica Societatis J´anos Bolyai, North-Holland, Amsterdam (1982) 835-873

[27] E. Sanchez-Palencia, Non-Homogeneous Media and Vibration Theory Springer Lecture Notes in Physics 129 (1980)

[28] S. Spagnolo, Sulla convergenza delle soluzioni di equazioni paraboliche ed ellittiche
Ann. Sc. Norm. Sup. Pisa Cl. Sci. (3) 22 (1968) 571-597

[29] S. Spagnolo, Convergence in energy for elliptic operators Proc. Third Symp. Numer.
Solut. Partial Diff. Equat. (College Park 1975), B. Hubbard ed., Academic Press, San
Diego (1976) 469-498

[30] L. Tartar, Quelques remarques sur l’homog´en´eisation Proc. of the Japan-France Seminar 1976 ”Functional Analysis and Numerical Analysis”, Japan Society for the Promotion of Sciences (1978) 469-482

[31] L. Tartar, Compensated compactness and partial differential equations, in Nonlinear
Analysis and Mechanics: Heriot-Watt Symposium vol. IV, pp.136-212, Pitman (1979)

[32] L. Tartar, The General Theory Of Homogenization, Lecture notes of the Unione
Matematica Italiana, 7, Springer (2010)

[33] V. Zhikov, S. Kozlov, O. Oleinik, Homogenization of Differential Operators Springer,
Berlin, (1995)

There are many books concerning different aspects of homogenization theory. Choose what interests you. Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, I recently started studying Homogenization with [11] and I think its good. I've found helpful the introduction to Analysis in their book. It's useful to have studied Functional Analysis before.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to thuanvu's pretty elaborate list I would like to add

[34] [G. Pavliotis, A. Stuart, Multiscale Methods: Averaging and Homogenization, Springer Science & Business Media, 2008.](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387738284)